# How does a Vampire Spawn become a Vampire?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

I was looking at the Vampire and Vampire Spawn entries in the monster manual, and a little blurb in the green box next to Von Zarovich's note talks about player characters becoming vampire spawns, then vampires. The step between living human and spawn is simple enough...

> A humanoid slain [with a vampire's bite] and then buried in the ground rises the following night as a vampire spawn under the vampire's control.

The step between Spawn and Vampire, however, seems a lot more fuzzy. How, exactly, does one make the transition from spawn to full-fledged vampire?

I'd prefer RAW, but i'll also take RAI or a homebrew option in its absence.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The step from Spawn to Vampire is described on page 295 of the Monster Manual as:

> If a true vampire allows a spawn to draw blood from its own body, the spawn transforms into a true vampire no longer under its master's control.

Interestingly enough, that suggests that *any* true Vampire can promote a Spawn, not just the Vampire that created the Spawn.

Comment: Huh, must have missed that one. I'll need to tag that for future reference. Got a page number for that?

Comment: Nevermind, found it myself, on a second look. In case anyone looks at this in the future, it's page 295, under "Born From Death"

Comment: @AmusableBman Thanks for asking this question btw, it gave me a great story idea! (Rival vampires freeing each others' servants.)

Comment: Depends on how much a vampire has control over its spawn... "Don't drink other vampires' blood!" and it's all over.